# Rails help deleting multiple

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having trouble deleting multiple konkurrancers with checkboxes.
I get this error in view when submitting my form:

```
  Routing Error

No route matches "/admin/konkurrancers/delete_multiple"
```

My index.erb.html:

```
<h1>Alle konkurrencer</h1>
<div id="konkurrancer"><%= render 'konkurrencer', :remote => true %></div>
<%= link_to 'Opret konkurrence', new_admin_konkurrancer_path, :class => 'link' %>
<%= link_to 'Tilbage', :admin, :class => 'admina' %>
```

My _konkurrencer partial:

```
  <% form_tag delete_multiple_admin_konkurrancers_path do %>
<div id="tabel">
<table id="tabel1" border="0" bordercolor="#000000" style="background-color:#FFFFFF" width="950" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr id="toptr">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td ><%= sortable "name", "Navn" %></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
<% for konkurrancer in @konkurrancers %>
   <tr class="thumbnail-item" onmouseout="this.style.background='white';" onmouseover="this.style.background='#99ff33';this.style.cursor='pointer'">
    <td><%= check_box_tag "konkurrancer_ids[]", konkurrancer.id %></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Vis', admin_konkurrancer_path(konkurrancer.id) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Redigere', {:action => 'edit', :id => konkurrancer.id}, :class => 'action edit' %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Slet', admin_konkurrancer_path(konkurrancer.id), :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
   </tr>
 <% end %>
</table>
<div id="pagenavi">
<%= submit_tag "Delete Checked" %>  
<% end %>  
<%= hidden_field_tag :direction, params[:direction] %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :sort, params[:sort] %>
</div>
```

My admin/konkurrancers controller:

```
def delete_multiple
    @konkurrancer = Konkurrancer.find(params[:konkurrancer_ids])
    @konkurrancer.each do |konkurrancer|
    konkurrancer.destroy
    end
end
```

My routes:

```
delete_multiple_admin_konkurrancers DELETE /admin/konkurrancers/delete_multiple(
.:format) {:action=>"delete_multiple", :controller=>"admin/konkurrancers"}
                admin_konkurrancers GET    /admin/konkurrancers(.:format)
          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"admin/konkurrancers"}
                                    POST   /admin/konkurrancers(.:format)
          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"admin/konkurrancers"}
             new_admin_konkurrancer GET    /admin/konkurrancers/new(.:format)
          {:action=>"new", :controller=>"admin/konkurrancers"}
            edit_admin_konkurrancer GET    /admin/konkurrancers/:id/edit(.:forma
t)        {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"admin/konkurrancers"}
                 admin_konkurrancer GET    /admin/konkurrancers/:id(.:format)
          {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/konkurrancers"}
                                    PUT    /admin/konkurrancers/:id(.:format)
          {:action=>"update", :controller=>"admin/konkurrancers"}
                                    DELETE /admin/konkurrancers/:id(.:format)
          {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"admin/konkurrancers"}
```

My routes.rb

namespace :admin do
    resources :konkurrancers do
      collection do
        delete :delete_multiple
      end
    end
  end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because the path you're looking for is not defined properly in your routes file.

I don't think that syntax is supported in rails3, you seem to be using a mix of rails3 and rails2.x.  Run `rake routes` from the root of the app, it will show you all the routes you have.  Using your syntax I get no mention of the `delete_multiple` path.  This should work:

```
  namespace :admin do
    resources :konkurrancers do
      collection do
        delete :delete_multiple
      end
    end
  end
```

Now, since you're using a standard form_tag, I believe the default method is POST, you want to change this to DELETE so the route works properly.  Change your form tag to:

```
form_tag delete_multiple_admin_konkurrancers_path, :method => :delete
```

Comment: now I get this error on submit: Routing Error

No route matches "/admin/konkurrancers/delete_multiple"

Comment: sorry, that's because you're probably POST'ng to it, which is the the default.

Comment: How do I change it to delete?

Comment: sorry, updated my post, note that you can see what method its using in the rails log, so check that when your form gets submitted,  you'll see a POST or GET somewhere.  This change should make it DELETE and it should work

Comment: How do I make a flash notice that displays all the names of the deleted konkurrancers as a list?